# How to reference GTK assemblies in MonoDevelop on ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, gtk, monodevelop

I've installed libgtk2.0-cil and libgtk2.0-cil-dev and gtk-sharp2 via apt

But when I open the References->Edit References->Packages it's not there.

https://www.monodevelop.com/help/faq/ says that MonoDevelop uses pgk-config and .pc files to locate assemblies.

There is a gtk-sharp-2.0.pc file in /usr/lib/pkgconfig

I'm using MonoDevelop 7.8.4 (build2) on Ubuntu 18.04

My project targets .net 4.8

How do I get MonoDevelop to discover my GTK sharp assemblies?

The assemblies also exist in the GAC

> gacutil -l | grep gdk
>
> policy.2.8.gtk-dotnet, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f policy.2.6.gtk-sharp, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f
>   policy.2.10.gtk-dotnet, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f policy.2.8.gtk-sharp, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f
>   policy.2.4.gtk-dotnet, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f gtk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f gtk-sharp,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f
>   policy.2.4.gtk-sharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f gtk-dotnet, Version=2.12.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f
>   policy.2.10.gtk-sharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f policy.2.6.gtk-dotnet,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop loads them from GAC, so your project file should contain,

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="gtk-sharp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="gdk-sharp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="glib-sharp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="glade-sharp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="pango-sharp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="atk-sharp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Mono.Posix" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: From the FAQ "MonoDevelop does not look for assemblies in the GAC. On Mac and Linux, MonoDevelop uses pkg-config to locate installed packages and get the list of assemblies that each package provides. A package specifies this list of assemblies in a .pc file which has to be installed in the standard pkg-config directory."

Comment: I think your answer may be correct on Windows, but it is wrong on ubuntu/linux, which is specifically mentioned in the question.

Comment: All I typed above came from the default GTK# project generated by VS for Mac (aka MonoDevelop) itself, and I am on Mac, not Windows. The FAQ and home page for MonoDevelop can be long out-of-date.

Comment: I'll try this tonight, however I will point out that References->Edit References->Packages does not include them as options, am I expected to manually add them to the GAC? Seems like if MonoDevelop used the GAC and they are added to the GAC by default then they would be in the references list already.

Comment: I tried creating a GTK# project using the MonoDevelop generator and all the gtk# assembly references have red x's beside them. MonoDevelop simply can't find the assemblies, but they are definitely installed.  My project file looks like yours.

Comment: How did you install Mono? If you strictly follow https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-ubuntu to install `mono-complete`, then GTK# assemblies are in GAC, and you can confirm by running `gacutil -l | grep gtk`.

Comment: I have followed the instructions and the assemblies are listed as being in the GAC, I have added gacutil -l | grep gtk results to my question. It still doesn't find them